# Создание многопоточности из основного потока [Delphi 7]

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, winsock

Имеется старое приложение (сервисное для игры), через которое происходит обращение к Web'у. Переписывание под *Delphi XE* невозможно, т.к. код слишком большой.

Как работает это всё: крутится основной поток в цикле `while` (обращение к Web-Серверу и tcp серверу), обрабатывая и передавая данные, все хорошо.

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы создавался ещё один поток из цикла `while`, пытаюсь делать это примерно так:

1. Работает основной поток (допустим, `TMain.Send`), он должен вызвать `TUpdate` и послать данные на веб-сервер, но ничего этого не происходит.

   ```
   procedure Tmain.Send;
   var Update:TUpdate;
   begin
     Update:=TUpdate.Create('domain.ru', '/index.php', 13000);
     update.worked:=true;
     //и все переменные объявлены
   end;
   ```
2. Полный код из новосозданного юнита.

   ```
     type TUpdate = class(TThread)
       private
       public
         worked:boolean;url,php:string;time:integer;
         function GetIPAddress(name: string):string;
         constructor Create(domain,data:string;timeout:integer);
       protected
         procedure HttpGet(url,php:String);
         procedure execute;override;
     end;


     constructor TUpdate.Create(domain,data:string;timeout:integer);
        begin
           inherited Create(False);
        end;

   procedure TUpdate.execute;
   var i:integer;
   begin
      while worked do
      begin
            HttpGet(url, php);
            if (time > 2000) then
            Sleep(time) else Sleep(500);
      end;
    end;


   function TUpdate.GetIPAddress(name: string):string;
   var
     p: PHostEnt;
   begin
   try
     p:=gethostbyname(pchar(name));
     if p=nil then result:=''
      else result:=inet_ntoa(PInAddr(p.h_addr_list^)^);
      except end;
   end;

   procedure TUpdate.HttpGet(url,php:String);
   var
     ws: TWSAData;
     TCP_sock:TSocket;
     SockAddr1:TSockAddr;
     packet:string;
     g,i:Integer;
     s:AnsiString;
     read:array[1..1024] of ansichar;
   begin
   WSAStartup($202,ws);
   TCP_sock:=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
   SockAddr1.sin_family:=AF_INET;
   SockAddr1.sin_port:=htons(80);
   SockAddr1.sin_addr.S_addr:=inet_addr(PChar(GetIPAddress(url)));
   connect(TCP_sock, SockAddr1, SizeOf(SockAddr1));
   packet:='GET '+php+' HTTP/1.1'+#13#10+
   'User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.7.62Version/11.00'+#13#10+
   'Host: '+url+#13#10+
   'Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml,image/png, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1'+#13#10+
   'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'+#13#10+
   'Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1, utf-8, utf-16, *;q=0.1'+#13#10+
   'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, x-gzip, identity, *;q=0'+#13#10+
   'Connection: close, TE'+#13#10+
   'TE: deflate, gzip, chunked, identity, trailers'+#13#10+#13#10;
   send(TCP_sock,packet[1],Length(Packet),0);
    s:='';
   repeat
     g:=recv(TCP_sock,read,SizeOf(read),0);
   for i:=1 to g do s:=s+(read[i]);
   until g<=0;
   CloseSocket(TCP_sock);
   WSACleanup;
   end;
   ```

Мне нужна помощь кодом. Может что-то упустил?

Comment: Эм... а где вы инициализируете внутренние поля класса `TUpdate`, в частности интересует поле `worked`. У вас оно по-умолчанию будет инициализирован в `False`, в итоге цикл в теле потока (`TUpdate.execute`) не выполняется, поток сразу же завершает работу

Comment: Упс... Забыл добавить в главном потоке все переменные объявлены,  boolean значение стоит truе.

Comment: За то время, пока ваш первый поток перейдет от строчки, в который создается поток, к строчке с `update.worked:=true;`, созданный поток `update` уже успевает войти в свой `Execute`, проверить значение поля `worked` и завершить свою работу, поскольку это поле все еще `False`.